# Using a member function with QScriptEngine::newFunction

Tags: c++, qt, qtscript

Let's take the case of a simple class:

```
QScriptEngine engine;

class MyClass {
public:
    QScriptValue foo(QScriptContext*, QScriptEngine*);
    MyClass();
};

QScriptValue MyClass:foo(QScriptContext* context, QScriptEngine* eng) {
    //something
}

MyClass::MyClass() {
    QScriptValue self = engine.newFunction(this->foo, 0);
    ....
}
```

The above function gives me an error:
`no matching function for call to ‘QScriptEngine::newFunction(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int)’`

I have tried using `engine.newFunction(reinterpret_cast<FunctionSignature>(foo), 0);` but this gives me an error which basically says that the compiler is not aware of a keyword called `'FunctionSignature'`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Regards,
rohan

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/10425-QtScript-newFunction-won-t-work I think this guys found the solution...

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the [official example code](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qscriptengine.html#newFunction), you should do something like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass() {
    QScriptValue self = engine.newFunction(foo, 0);
    ....
}
```

**EDIT:** OK, I looked into the reference a little bit more. The problem is, that you try to pass a method, where a function is needed. As @[mosg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299909/mosg) pointed out, this isn't possible. Either you make `foo` a static function - or you try the solution in the referenced thread. This means, that you create a new `QObject` via `engine.newQObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution static method:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static QScriptValue foo(QScriptContext*, QScriptEngine*);
    MyClass();
};

...

QScriptValue func = engine.newFunction(MyClass::foo)
```