# Using QScriptEngine with a "native function" call... QT Example... fails: "no matching function for call to 'QScriptEngine::newFunction' "?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am using an example provide by Qtcreator and getting this error...  ??

[image]

```
void MainWindow::hBtn
{
    QScriptEngine e;

    QScriptValue fun = e.newFunction(myAdd);  // ERROR: No matching function...
    e.globalObject().setProperty("myAdd", fun);

    QScriptValue result = e.evaluate("myAdd(myNumber, 1)");
}


QScriptValue myAdd(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine)
//also tried:  QScriptValue MainWindow::myAdd(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine) //fails as well with same ERROR
{
   QScriptValue a = context->argument(0);
   QScriptValue b = context->argument(1);
   return a.toNumber() + b.toNumber();
}
```

---

Example:  http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qscriptengine.html

scroll down to "Native Functions"

---

Looked through another user having problems with no solution either:  [Using a member function with QScriptEngine::newFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935802/using-a-member-function-with-qscriptenginenewfunction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used as basis:  [Pass member function pointer in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257239/pass-member-function-pointer-in-c)

I took the "myAdd" declaration out of the header class... problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an `int` for the second parameter. `QScriptValue` is not `int` related.

**Edit:** Ok, just realized that there is another possible combination using `QScriptValue`, but you may have to pass also an `int` and make `fun` a constant.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried another QTCreator example... issue is with engine.newFunction() ... ??

Comment: I can't help you with that. I would have to test it but I can't.
Nevertheless, did you try to fulfill the parameter combinations as I suggested?